# Moon-egg? Pigeon fanciers? Telepathic dolphins?

Tags: story-identification

This is a long shot ... The book I'm looking for is juvenile SF which I read in the early 80s.  A young teen boy who breeds pigeons discovers that 1) the moon is a giant egg and 2) dolphins are sentient and possibly connected to the giant moon-egg.  I'm pretty sure it's British (at one point he refers to the "sodding egg").

Answer (score 17):

I believe what you are seeking is ***World-Eater*** by Robert E. Swindells.

[image]

It was first published in the UK in 1983, and then again in 1987 in hardback by Hodder Children's Books.  It is a fairly compact novel — about 100 pages, depending on which printing you read.

The main character is a boy named Orville Copperstone.  He breeds pigeons and looks forward to a particular pigeon's eggs hatching.

But you may be misremembering a few details.  The giant egg in the sky is not the moon but rather a new planet that has suddenly appeared in our solar system, between Mercury and Venus.  Scientists realize that the "planet" consists of a thin spherical shell filled with a viscous liquid, and Orville theorizes that it is a giant bird's egg.  When the scientists finally listen to Orville and confirm his theory, a disaster of epic proportions is averted.

The novel contains the following line:

> "Activity inside that goddam egg's increasing."

I suspect this is your *sodding egg*.